# Question concerning the proof of regularity for the Laplacian $f \in H^m(\Omega) \Rightarrow u \in H^{m+2}(\Omega) $

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, proof-explanation, regularity-theory-of-pdes, weak-derivatives

I am stuck at the proof of Theorem 9.25 in Haim Brezis' *Sobolev Spaces, Functional Analysis and Partial Differential Equations*.

This theorem deals with the regularity for the Dirichlet Problem for the Laplacian. That is, we assume that $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and that verifies: $$\int \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi + \int u   \varphi = \int f  \varphi $$

I have already shown that if $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ then $u \in H^2(\Omega)$ for $\Omega$ of class $C^2$. Now I want to show that if $f \in H^m(\Omega)$ then $u \in H^{m+2}(\Omega)$ for $\Omega$ of class $C^{m+2}$.

The book leaves this to the user and says it can be deduced for any set $\Omega$ of class $C^{m+2}$ as in cases $\Omega= \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Omega= \mathbb{R}^n_+ =\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ x_n>0 \}$.

In these cases this is done by showing that $Du$ verifies the equation: $$\int \nabla (Du) \cdot \nabla \varphi + \int Du \  \varphi = \int (Df)  \varphi$$

And then applying the first part for this equation. To do this we have to show that $Du \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. In the case $\Omega= \mathbb{R}^n$ this is obvious since $H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n)=H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

In the case $\Omega= \mathbb{R}^n_+$ this is done by using the following trick:

[image]

[image]

He uses **tangential translations**, that is, $h \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ x_n=0 \}$, this means $D_hu= \frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{|h|}$ belongs to $H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^n_+)$, as $ h +\mathbb{R}^n_+ =\mathbb{R}^n_+$.

Here comes the problem. For a general domain, how do I use the trick of translations?

Answer (score 1):

One doesn't use translations for a general domain. One uses a diffeomorphism between a part of the domain, and half-space, and then translates in the half-space. This is what Brezis does later in the text (part C); you quoted some of it in [Concerning the proof of regularity of the weak solution for the laplacian problem given in Brezis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1796064).

Comment: Should I translate it the same way $u$ is translated? By using partitions of unity?

Comment: I mean translate $Du$

Comment: Does one follow the exact same proof transfering first $u$ and then shows $Du \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ once  $u$ lives on $Q_+$?

Comment: There is something I don't understand: Let's suppose we have to show that $f \in H^1(\Omega) \Rightarrow u \in H^3(\Omega)$. Then the hypothesis says $\Omega$ of class $C^3$ is needed. I don't get why. Why not just simply translate $Du$ by using partitions of unity and then using $H$ ? It should be only needed $\Omega$ of class $C^2$.

Comment: To summarize, Where is the hypothesis "$\Omega$ of class $C^3$" used?